# Multiple label in angular mat slide toggle

Tags: angular, angular-material

I using angular 8 and angular materail I dont now how to have a slide toggle button with 2 label.

```
<mat-label> {{ label1 }} </mat-label>
<mat-slide-toggle> {{ label2 }} </mat-slide-toggle>
```

this html code isn't dosent have a good design because the labels are not align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**html**

```
<section class="example-section">
  <mat-label> {{ label1 }} </mat-label>
  <mat-slide-toggle
      class="example-margin">
    {{ label2 }}
  </mat-slide-toggle>
</section>
```

**css**

```
.example-section {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.example-margin {
  margin: 10px;
}
```